# How to git push to GitHub in a pipeline using GitHub Actions

Tags: bash, git, github, github-actions

I am building a pipeline using GitHub Actions and bash scripts.

I want an action to push a tag and a commit when I am doing a release (`mvn deploy`). How can this be done in a pipeline using https and adding credentials?

In the script below, how do I add credentials to the `git push origin vx.y.z`?

```
echo "Creating tag: $MY_TAG"

git config --global user.email "my@action.com"
git config --global user.name "release-git-tag GitHub Action"

git tag -a ${MY_TAG} -m "$GITHUB_ACTOR released artifact: $MY_TAG"

<how to: git push origin ${MY_TAG}>
```

Comment: https://github.com/butlerlogic/action-autotag

Comment: I am trying to build a standalone pipeline which requires no inputs to the actions. The only valid input in a workflow file is to set environment variables. This is why I need a solution to git push to an existing repo using https in a bash script.

Comment: What do you mean pushing a tag and commit? A release already creates a tag for the last commit, why do you also want to push a commit?

Comment: what do you mean? is a tag automatically created when you run mvn deploy with GitHub Packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `origin` and add the credentioals there.

Assuming your origin is `https://github.com/USER/REPO.git`, you can add the credentials using `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/USER/REPO.git`. With the environment varuables, it would be:

```
https://${GITHUB_ACTOR}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/USER/REPO.git
```

The command will be:

```
git remote set-url origin https://${GITHUB_ACTOR}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/USER/REPO.git
```

(Don't forget to replace `USER` and `REPO`)